# How to automatically create a new table row

Tags: php, arrays, loops, html-table

I need some help generating a table with PHP.

I have an array with 10 -15 entries. 
Like this:

```
$array = array(IME1, IME2, IME3, IME4,IME5, IME6, IME7 ,IME8 ,IME9 ,IME10);
```

The goal is to create a table like this: on every 3rd entry an automatic new row.

[image: example]

Can someone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a job for **[`array_chunk()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)**

```
array_chunk($array, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest solution

```
$chunks = array_chunk($array, $max_col); 
$max_col = 3; 
?>
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <? foreach($chunks as $key => $value){
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach($value as $k => $v){
                echo "<td> ".$v." </td>";
            }
            // Finish tr, but only if there are no items left for the next row
            if( count($value) == $max_col ){
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
        // Finish td with an empty value setting colspan if there are not enough items to fil the entire row
        if( count($value) < $max_col ){
            echo "<td colspan=".($max_col-count($v)-1)."></td>";
            // Finish the last row
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Think about separating your logic from your presentation. There are numerous template engines out there that would solve this problem in a breeze or let you define a function/modifier/snippet that takes care of this task and let you easily reuse it.